# Showing Time Spent Today and Time Spent Total in Time Tracker App

Tags: interface, users, time, duration

Currently, our team is developing a time tracker for employees to time in and time out during their shifts.

In the time tracker are tasks listed. Each task (e.g. Read emails, read backlogs) has a text beside it that indicates how many hours the employee has timed in that task for the shift.

However, we're also planning to show the total amount of time he/she has timed in during that task (all shifts).

Any idea on how we can approach this one without causing confusion?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean two time columns, one labeled "Current Shift" and another labeled "All Shifts"?

Comment: There are a few ways you could do this. Why would your user need to see their total time on a task across all shifts? What does this information do for them?

Comment: same questions, what insight can they possibly get for know time spent on "read email task" across all shifts...?

Comment: "Why would your user need to see their total time on a task" - It gives them context on how frequent they time in to that task.

Comment: "Do you mean two time columns, one labeled "Current Shift" and another labeled "All Shifts"?" Hmm, not necessarily. I think space-wise, that is a bit challenging showing two time columns. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is a standardized way of defining what a single shift is (whether it is a window of time or fixed hours), then you can simply create one column to display this information, and another column to display the total amount of time.

This type of information display is perfectly suited to a data table, and allows the user to quickly scan across the header rows to get to the information that they are looking for. A column heading of 'task', 'time - current shift' and 'time- all shifts' should be clear enough, or you can create a column for 'time' and split it into 'current shift' and 'total' should also be clear enough.